# How to solve permission when running bash command from java

Tags: java, bash

When I run commands from the console everything is OK:

```
sudo -u oracle fgrep ...
```

When I run the same command from Java code using `ProcessBuilder`, sudo doesn't work, and I need to set chmod to 775 or else I don't have permission to read logs.

Why doesn't this work? Is there an option to read logs without chmod 775?

Here is how I am using `ProcessBuilder`:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", command);
Process shell = pb.start();

InputStream is = shell.getInputStream();
```

Comment: What is the Java code you're using?

Comment: Does your command ask for an input?

Comment: what you mean with input ? there is some parameter

Comment: @hudi -- like, does it expect a password to be entered ... like `sudo` typically does?

Comment: nope  pass isnt expected

Comment: If the SUDO command asks for a password then the process that you created will keep on waiting...

Comment: like I said processor builder is not waiting because pass is not expected. There is just exception that I dont have persmsion if I dont set chmod to 775

Comment: All i can think of is may be you are running the command as root but your java program as a normal user

Comment: this command is runing under account oracle which has access to file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say `chmod 775` for log file it works, it's obvious your process doesn't have permission.

You can run your java with sudo:

```
sudo java ClassFileName
```

Or just add `sudo` as the first string in the array that you pass to bash process:

```
command[0]="sudo -u oracle ";

//command[1]=commandname;

//command[2...n]=Other params;
```

Assuming user `oracle` is in sudoers list and won't ask for password, this will run just like how it runs in commandline when you use `sudo`.

Comment: and what about bash and -c ? my command look like ... new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", "sudo -u oracle fgrep ...");

Comment: Yes. That's right. When it's executed in the shell it would look like: `bach -c "sudo commandname param1 param2 ..."`

Answer (score 0):

a. You don't need the bash -c, when you're executing the command you have a shell.

b. The command needs to be split on spaces and then passed into the ProcessBuilder as an array.

Comment: why array ? Parameter for PB is String ... not array

Comment: If you look closely it is a String array: `ProcessBuilder(String... command)`

Comment: there isnt problem with this because when I set chmod to 775 this works so I run command corrctly

Comment: Hah! What a jacked spec :http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#ProcessBuilder(java.lang.String...)  This is miserable. My sincere condolences and im going to retract my answer simply because you validated its statement about user credentials